# How to add close_above_open for a buy indicator in MQL4?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, trading, mql4, forex, technical-indicator

Is that possible to add a `close_above_open` condition too in the pattern of `iHigh() && iClose() && iLow()`?

I.e. I would like to add the `close_above_open` in the below code. Can you help me to know the method?

```
  const int timePeriodD1=PERIOD_D1;

  if(iHigh(symbol,timePeriodD1,1)>iHigh(symbol,timePeriodD1,2) && iClose(symbol,timePeriodD1,1) >iClose(symbol,timePeriodD1,2) &&
     iLow(symbol,timePeriodD1,1)>iLow(symbol,timePeriodD1,2)){
           //ObjectSetText(d1label,"UP",11, "Verdana", Aqua);
           d1result="UP";
  }else if(iHigh(symbol,timePeriodD1,1)<iHigh(symbol,timePeriodD1,2) && iClose(symbol,timePeriodD1,1) < iClose(symbol,timePeriodD1,2) &&
     iLow(symbol,timePeriodD1,1)< iLow(symbol,timePeriodD1,2)){
           //ObjectSetText(d1label,"DOWN",11, "Verdana", Yellow);
           d1result="DOWN";
        }else{
           //ObjectSetText(d1label,"MIXED",11, "Verdana", White);
           d1result="MIXED";
        }
```

Simply asking is there any way to write as below:

```
if(iHigh(symbol,timePeriodD1,1)>iHigh(symbol,timePeriodD1,2) && iClose(symbol,timePeriodD1,1) >iClose(symbol,timePeriodD1,2) &&
iLow(symbol,timePeriodD1,1)>iLow(symbol,timePeriodD1,2) &&
CloseAboveOpen(symbol,timePeriodD1,1)>CloseAboveOpen(symbol,timePeriodD1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Q1** : <sub>Is that possible to add a `close_above_open` condition too in the pattern of `iHigh() && iClose() && iLow()`?</sub>

Yes, it is:

```
...
if (           iHigh( symbol, timePeriodD1, 1 ) >          iHigh( symbol, timePeriodD1, 2 )
   &&         iClose( symbol, timePeriodD1, 1 ) >         iClose( symbol, timePeriodD1, 2 )
   &&           iLow( symbol, timePeriodD1, 1 ) >           iLow( symbol, timePeriodD1, 2 )
   && CloseAboveOpen( symbol, timePeriodD1, 1 ) > CloseAboveOpen( symbol, timePeriodD1, 2 )
      ){ ... }
...
```

> **Q2** : <sub>Simply asking is there any way to write it as below...?</sub>

Yes, there is.
May try to customize this template to match your further needs:

```
int CloseAboveOpen( string aSymbolNAME,       /// [DOC-me] Ret-s {+|-}n-pts above Open
                       int aTimeFRAME,
                       int nOffsetBARs ) {
    
    return( (int)( ( iClose( aSymbolNAME, aTimeFRAME, nOffsetBARs )
                   -  iOpen( aSymbolNAME, aTimeFRAME, nOffsetBARs )
                     )
                   * MathPow( 10, (int)MarketInfo( aSymbolNAME, MODE_DIGITS ) )
                   )
            );
                 
    }
```